# Having issue with HeaderRowRange to loop through all headers and change their values

Tags: excel, vba

I was trying to loop through all headers in my table on Excel to change their values, unless there is a better approach.

The idea is to check if the table already exists and if it does not, create a new table, however and since it's not possible (to my knowledge) to create the table and give names to headers before creating, I have to  change their names after. For that I was trying to use the **.HeaderRowRange.Address** to loop true all cells in that range and change the values of headers, but the **With tCells** is not being triggered

This is the code I have:

```
Sub novaLinha()
Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim tCells As Ranges
Dim tCell As Range

On Error Resume Next

Set ws = Worksheets("Dados")

If ws.ListObjects.count Then

Else
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range(cells(1, 1), cells(1, 5)), , xlYes)

    With tbl
        .Name = "TabelaDados"
        .TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium2"
        Set tCells = Range(.HeaderRowRange.Address)
        Debug.Print Range(.HeaderRowRange.Address)
        With tCells
            Debug.Print tCells
            For Each tCell In tCells
                Debug.Print tCell
            Next tCell
        End With
    End With
End If

'iRow = ws.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
'ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = ws.ListObjects.count
Exit Sub
    If Err.Number > 0 Then
        Debug.Print Err.Number & ":" & Err.Description
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you get some error? You should get rid of `On Error Resume Next`.

Comment: when trying to debug with the immediate window it just not shows nothing at all after that with... no errors as well. I just have it there to make sure all is ok, while doing/writing the code

Comment: You are using `Exit Sub` before your error handler. So even if Err.Number > 0, you won't print the error.

Comment: humm you sure about that ? i mean i was using the same method on the form button click and it was showing the errors

Comment: I am 100% sure that `Exit Sub` executs before your `If Err.Number...` statement.

Comment: you right... i migh have understood that part wrong https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/exit-statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to iterate over the `tbl.HeaderRowRange.Cells` directly:

```
With tbl
    .Name = "TabelaDados"
    .TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium2"
    For Each tCell In tbl.HeaderRowRange.Cells
        Debug.Print tCell
    Next tCell
End With
```

Note comments above re: error-handling:

- You are using `Exit Sub` before your error handler. So even if `Err.Number > 0`, you won't print the error.
- `On Error Resume Next` simply tells the IDE to *ignore any and all errors*. This means that errors can compound and lead to further errors, which then become the more difficult to troubleshoot. It's generally frowned upon to use `On Error Resume Next` *especially* when you've wrapped the entire executable body of your subroutine in that sort of handler. There are some limited/single-use functions that make use of this construct, but that is not a good idea to implement in this case.

> it's not possible (to my knowledge) to create the table and give names to headers before creating

Here this is possible, if you first populate the cells that will comprise the range, and *then* add a table:

```
Dim hdrRange As Range
Set hdrRange = Range("A1:E1")
Const HEADERS As String = "Alpha,Beta,Gamma,Delta,Epsilon"
hdrRange.Value = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Split(HEADERS, ",")))
' Creates table with the headers already in place:
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 5)), , xlYes)

With tbl
    .Name = "TabelaDados"
    .TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium2"
    For Each tCell In tbl.HeaderRowRange.Cells
        Debug.Print tCell
    Next tCell
End With
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: ahh so it's possible to create the headers when we create the table nice... I did read several times the help from the official site and i did try using the "Destination" option from add method but with out success. I start wondering it was not possible. Thanks in advance will test it to see and will upvote if...

Comment: ahh so it's not indeed possible to create the table with headers you just using the Transpose method to populate the future header cell values ... nice method by the way i was not away of that one

Comment: i noted you did not declared the variable tCell. Isn't that one needed to be declared ? If not why ?
Thanks advance

Comment: Yes, but you already declared it. I only included the relevant snippet of code that I modified, which the first case didn't use any new declarations.

Comment: Yes, I just populate headers in advance. This could be done manually (not part of macro). The idea is that you insert table and existing values will become the headers, otherwise it uses the defaults like "Column 1", etc.